# How to do a XSL transform in Java using a not namespace aware parser?

Tags: java, xslt, sax, tag-soup

I use [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/) as (SAX) `XMLREader` and set the namespace feature to `false`. This parser is used to feed the `Transformer` as SAX Source. Complete code:

```
    final TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    final Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(
        getClass().getResourceAsStream("/identity.xsl")));

    final XMLReader p = new Parser(); // the tagsoup parser
    p.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);

    // getHtml() returns HTML as InputStream
    final Source source = new SAXSource(p, new InputSource(getHtml())); 

    t.transform(source, new StreamResult(System.out));
```

This results in something like:

```
< xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<>
<>
<>
<>
< height="17" valign="top">
```

Problem is that the tag names are blank. The XMLReader (tagsoup parser) does report an empty namespaceURI and empty local name in the SAX methods `ContentHandler#startElement` and `ContentHandler#endElement`. For a not namespace aware parser this is allowed (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#startElement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes))).

If i add a `XMLFilter` which copies the value of the qName to the localName, everything goes fine. However, this is not what i want, i expect this works "out of the box". What am i doing wrong? Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to use XSLT with an XmlReader that does not support namespaces? XSLT/XPath are known to require namespace well-formed input.

Comment: If namespaces are enabled, i need xpath expressions like `h:html/h:body/h:table/h:tbody/h:tr` instead of `html/body/table/tbody/tr` (short answer: because i am lazy and/or my knowledge of xslt sucks).

Comment: Note that TagSoup according to http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/#program has an option `--nons` to suppress namespaces (Namespaces are suppressed.). I would guess that you can enable that as well using its API and in that case when you parse HTML the elements reported should be in no namespace (which XSLT/XPath can handle).

Comment: @MartinHonnen `--nons` command line option is the same as `p.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);` used in my example. Suppressing namespaces is actually where i am looking for!

Comment: If the command line option simply sets that parser feature then I agree with answer of Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect this works "out of the box". What am i doing wrong?

What you are doing wrong is taking a technology (XSLT) that is defined to operate over namespace-well-formed XML and attempting to apply it to data that it is not intended to work with.  If you want to use XSLT then you *must* enable namespaces, declare a prefix for the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace in your stylesheet, and use that prefix consistently in your XPath expressions.

If your transformer understands XSLT 2.0 (e.g. [Saxon 9](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)) then instead of declaring a prefix and prefixing your element names in XPath expressions, you can put `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element to make it treat unprefixed element names as references to that namespace.  But in XSLT 1.0 (the default built-in Java `Transformer` implementation) your only option is to use a prefix.

Comment: Very clear answer! For me the missing link was: If you want to use XSLT then you must enable namespaces **on the input document**. I do know about the XSLT 2 feature, but for this project, only XSLT 1 is available and i really hate to use the prefixes over and over again, so disabling namespaces on the input document was meant to be smart :)

Comment: As an addition: i cannot find a mention in the Javadoc about this precondition!